# Code thread error?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)fartButton:(id)sender
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURL;
    soundFileURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Fart", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURL, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}

- (IBAction)vomitButton:(id)sender
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURL;
    soundFileURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Vomit", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURL, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}

@end
```

and for some reason it pulls up a thread issue with AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURL, &soundID);

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: It wont let me post pics, but it says Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1

Comment: Can you just copy & paste the error?

Comment: Could it be that you just have a breakpoint on that line?

Comment: How would i fix a break point

Comment: UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURL, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);         Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1